# For new record, autonumber value is out of sequence

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

[image: Access Table]

CPTY_PK is an AutuNumber Primary key . I used an left join between two tables and wanted to add records which are not in this table . When I ran the Query , the new records were added but the autonumber incresed from 613 to 7679 . I dont how it can jump in thousands . I am of the view that this is because of join and I want to know any other reason or solution behind this .

SQL query that I used :

**db.Execute "INSERT INTO D_Counterparty (CPTY_ENTITY_ID,CPTY_DESC)"_
& "SELECT Ctpy_Entity_Id,Ctpy_Entity_Legal_Nm"_
& "FROM NewCU LEFT JOIN D_Counterparty ON D_Counterparty.CPTY_ENTITY_ID=NewCU.Ctpy_Entity_Id"**

Comment: I wouldn't be overly concerned with it, since an AutoNumber PK is nothing more than a surrogate key, and has no meaning to your data. I assume there are other fields which define the uniqueness of your data. That said, you might consider compacting your database, since this will reset the seed value for all PK fields.

Comment: Hi, you are right that I have ither fields defining the uniqueness of my data , but I need to update the corresponding AutoNumber field in to another table compulsarily.Is there any way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Access 2000 and later, an AutoNumber field may begin assigning extreme values, negatives, and even duplicates... it may not be possible to save new records in an affected table.

-- http://allenbrowne.com/ser-40.html

This is likely your problem, and the illustrious Allen Browne will lead you through the remedy, which involves re-seeding the autokey value but also probably improving your database or application design to prevent the root issue.

However, also make sure the Autokey method has not been changed from incremental to random.  (I think this is probably not possible... see http://msgroups.net/microsoft.public.access/autonumber-from-random-to-incremental/40134.)

I don't think your query is the problem, because `CPTY_PK` is not in that query.  The cause could be from events happening you haven't shown here, but this looks like the broken-authonumber issue and I can't easily imagine it is anything else.

Comment: I tried the Allenbrowne module but it gives me 0 as the answer i.e no chnages made and even the autokey is on incremental . Thanks for the answer and let me know if you get some further thoghts . by the time I will try making some changes . Is this because of the join ?

Comment: If you tried my suggestion and you still have the issue, you may want to un-accept this answer!

Comment: `Is this because of the join?` -- see my edit to answer